# C# Get Name of Derived Type from Inside base Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

During a debug session, it's important for me to identify the name of the actual derived class *in the debug info* of specific instances.

I tried using `this.GetType().Name` but this simply returns the type of the `base` class.

Is there a simple way to get the type of the derived class from within the base class?

Answer (score 68):

`this.GetType().Name` should work. I think, in your case, you may not have a derived class. If it's returning the base class name, it shouldn't have a derived class.

Using this on:

1. Base class - Outputs Base class name
2. Derived class - Outputs Derived class name
3. Derived class cast to Base class - Outputs Derived class name
4. Derived class passed into a function that accepts Base class as a parameter - Outputs Derived class name

Answer (score 15):

`this.GetType().Name` always return the name of the current executing type, not the type that the code that it was written in. You can emulate breakpoints though, using `Debugger.Break()` in a conditional manner:

```
if (this.GetType().Name == "Problematic type")
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 2):

> During a debug session...

Remember that instead halting a session to add some throw-away code to then recompile and restart, *one can use the debugger to divine that* after the breakpoint is hit...

By utilizing the `Immediate Window` of the debugger and typing a `this.GetType().Name` off of the instance in question and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be shown.

See VS Docs: [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2017)

> Is there a simple way to get the type of the derived class from within the base class?

Yes, for an example I can determine what the exception is by using the `Name` property of `GetType` and in real time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When raising an event, be sure to pass the real sender to the sender property. The sender object in the listening class should correctly point to the child class that raised the event.