# How to know caller class C#

Tags: c#, class

I have the below class structure. Class A is called from constructor of Class B and C.

```
Class A
{
    A()
}

Class B
{
    B()
    {
        A();
    }
}

Class C
{
    C()
    {
        A();
    }
}
```

Is there a way where I can get to know if the call to A() comes from B() or C()?
I do not want to pass any object in the constructor.

Comment: Might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1375429/6299857

Comment: Not directly. It is probably bad practice to have the behaviour of A depend on the class that uses it - next time you want to use A from a totally different class you will get a surprise. It is best to pass in all inputs via parameters to the constructor, so that it is obvious how A works and so that it can be easily used by other classes (reusability!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me

```
var mth = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
var cls = mth.ReflectedType.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to get caller name. Please check the following example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information). Hope this will help.

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output:
//  message: Something happened.
//  member name: DoProcessing
//  source file path: c:\Visual Studio Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs
//  source line number: 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **CallerMemberNameAttribute** or **CallerFilePathAttribute**.
Please refer to Microsoft's doc for more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information

```
public class FirstClass
{
     public string Run([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "")
    {
        return $"CallerMemberName is {memberName}. Calling from {sourceFilePath}";
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string CallFirstClass()
    {
        var firstClass = new FirstClass();
        return firstClass.Run();
    }
}
```

the output in the CallFirstClass() would be like this

```
CallerMemberName is CallFirstClass. Calling from D:\Development\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\SecondClass.cs
```